# HTML form with multiple “actions”

Tags: php, html, forms, google-docs

I'm trying to create a form to send data to gdoc and mail. 
   Separately work properly but will need to work from the same button

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/code/formResponse" method="POST" name="ss-form" id="ss-form" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
```

and

```
<form name="frmContact" method="post" action="../sendData.php">
```

Comment: use ajax to submit those forms

Comment: you can't have 2 form actions if that is what you are asking

Comment: Are you able to modify the sendData.php? Couldn't you just decide what to do with the data in this file (in this case two actions) ?